# How to set an environment variable in config.js of a node.js microservice?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node.js application built using graphql. I need to check an 'environment variable' to see what environment I'm on (development, testing, production). Based on that environment, I need to set a url. I think I have a vague idea of what I need but don't know how to accomplish it.

Currently my config.js file looks something like this:

```
       const configuration = convict({
          env: {
              format: ['development', 'testing', 'production'],
              default: 'development',
              arg: 'nodeEnv',
              env: 'NODE_ENV'
         }

         const env = configuration.get('env');
         configuration.loadFile(`./config/${env}.json`);
         configuration.validate({allowed: 'strict'});

         module.exports = configuration.getProperties();
     )};
```

And then in a separate file where I actually need to set the url based on the environment, I need to do so based on the kind of environment (development, test or production) that I'm on. The code in that file would be:

```
        If(env=='development'){
           const url = 'abc.def.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/graphql';
        }
        Else If (env == 'testing'){
           const url = 'xxx.yyyy.com/abc/def/ghi/graphql';
        }
        Else{
           const url = '123.abc.com/cdc/def/hhh/graphql';
        }
```

I tried to console.log the env value but when I try the following:
               console.log( env );

I get an error: Reference error: env is not defined.

Can someone point me to what I'm missing/doing wrong to access the env variable?

Comment: You can use process.env.NODE_ENV to get the current node environment.

Comment: @Neeraj Wadhwa - when I try that in console.log I get 'undefined'

Comment: @RogerDodger You can set it in the code process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'; or start your process with it  NODE_ENV=production node app.js

Comment: Export the config as module.exports = configuration and in the other file you need to require it like const config = require(‘./config.js’) and in that file do config.get(‘env’).

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa - my file structure is like so: myNodeApp/config.js (this is where the config file is); the file that I'm trying to get the environment info is structured like so: myNodeApp/source1/source2/source3/myFile.js; so I set the config at the top of the file in myFile.js like so: const config = require('../../../config.js'); but when I try to console log it like you suggested - I get error: config.get is not a function

Comment: @mexo - I'm not sure what the entry point for my app is since I downloaded a starter kit and am not fully familiar with it - right now, I start my app with the following on the command like: npm start -- do I need to add params to that?

Comment: Please confirm that you are exporting configuration as module.exports = configuration;

Comment: Or if you want to export as module.exports = configuration.getProperties();, then console log the whole export to see what you get there. console.log(JSON.stringify(config));

Comment: In my OP above, I had that code snippet if you check: module.exports = config.getProperties();

Comment: Did you try logging the configuration export?

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa - Can you expound on that? I tried logging it like so: const config = require('../../../config.js');  console.log(config.getProperties());

Comment: What is the output that you get? If you see env as key there then you can use it as config.env

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa - If I try config.getProperties() my app errors out with 'No function called config.getProperties(); if I try it with process.env.NODE_ENV I get an undefined in the console.

Comment: If you have exported the module as module.exports = configuration.getProperties(); then you shouldn’t call getProperties() function again after requiring it in another file.

Comment: I removed that; instead I required config.js at the top of my file: const config = require('../../../config.js'); and then later in the file I tried logging it as console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);

Answer (score 3):

You can access them like this:

```
process.env.VARIABLE_NAME
```

Comment: mexo - I started my app in command line like so: npm start --development  ; then in my file I tried console logging as console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) but I keep getting undefined in the console

Comment: Yes this worked: NODE_ENV=development npm start - thanks Neeraj!! How do I accept your answer? I don't see a check mark next to your answer.

Comment: Currently - this solution works if I manually start the node.js program at command line with NODE_ENV=development npm start; but when I deploy my application into testing and production, it's an automated process - so I need a way to do it through code - I tried adding it in "scripts":"NODE_ENV=dev" but that doesn't work. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: @NeerajWadhwa - your solution worked when I set the variables manually by typing them in on the command line, but I need to be able to set these dynamically at run time, based on the environment once it's deployed to the cloud. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You can try exporting the config as module.exports = configuration; and after requiring it in other module, just do config.get(‘env’).

Comment: You are also trying to load the file based on env, does that file exist?